# Rails How to define a macro to use only within factories.rb

Tags: factory-bot

I'm using FactoryGirl in a Rails application for RSpec functional testing. While writing factories I came across a need for defining private method or macro to remove the duplicate code in factories. The macros should be such that it can only be called from factories definition. Kindly help

```
factory :subscriber, :class => Subscriber do                                                                                                   
  sequence(:name) { |n| "test_user_#{n}" }                                                                                                     
  sequence(:email) { |n| "test_user_#{n}@example.com"}                                                                                                                   
  association :authentication, factory: :authentication                                                            

  factory :subscriber_with_subscription do                                                                                                     

    ignore do
      payment_pending_subscriptions 0                                                                                                          
      purchased_subscriptions 0
      active_subscriptions 0                                                                                                           
    end                                                                                                                                        

    after(:create) do |subscriber, evaluator|                                                                                                  

      count = evaluator.payment_pending_subscriptions
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:subscription, count, status: 'payment_pending', :subscriber => subscriber) if count >0                         

      count = evaluator.purchased_subscriptions
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:subscription, count, status: 'purchased', :subscriber => subscriber) if count > 0

      count = evaluator.active_subscriptions
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:subscription, count, status: 'active', :subscriber => subscriber) if count > 0
    end
  end
end
```

if I can define a method inside the factory such that

```
def create_subs count, status
  FactoryGirl.create_list(:subscription, count, status: status, :subscriber => subscriber) if count > 0
end
```

Then the calls can be reduced to one line / state

```
create_subs evaluate.purchased_subscription, "purchased_subscription"
```

But even after defining create_subs, it gives error that it is not found.

Comment: If we knew what you were actually trying to do, we may be able to help.

Comment: edited the post to give a detailed picture.